# aspx with image doesn't display when is invoked from <img src="with_Image.aspx" >

Tags: asp.net, image

I've got two aspx pages: Default.aspx and with_Image.aspx.
From Default.aspx, I tried to show a jpg image that is in with_Image.aspx.
with_Image.aspx displays the jpg image without problems. But Default.aspx doesn't display any image, only displays an "X".

On Default.aspx:

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">

    <div>
    <img src="with_Image.aspx" runat="server" id="imgCaptcha" />    
    </div>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

On with_Image.aspx:

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">    
        <img src="image.jpg" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

What is missing?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't working for you because the src attribute of an img tag needs to be the [URL of an image file](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/img), but you've got it pointed to a web page (with_Image.aspx) instead.

Answer (score 0):

What you ask is not possible.

You'll need to use either jquery, an iframe, or streamwrite it into your webpage from asp.net to insert a separate web page into your html code.

Also what you're doing isn't exactly best practice, plus it'll cause an error due to having 2 forms with runat="server".

Answer (score 0):

Question from 2012 but I guess I will provide an answer for it.

I just did a project with the similar setup and this is my solution.

Default.aspx

```
<td style="width:80%">
    <img id="imgCaptcha" runat="server" />
</td>
```

Default.aspx.cs

```
imgCaptcha.Src = "Image.aspx?path" + ImagePath;
```

My Image.aspx is blank but with the following code in Image.aspx.cs

```
string path = Request.QueryString["path"].ToString(); 
string ext = path.Substring(path.LastIndexOf("."));
if (File.Exists(path))
{
    Response.Clear();
    Response.ClearHeaders();
    switch (ext.ToUpper())
    {
        case ".JPG":
        case ".JPEG": Response.ContentType = "image/JPEG";
            break;
        case ".GIF": Response.ContentType = "image/GIF";
            break;
        case ".PDF": Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
            break;
    }
    Response.WriteFile(path, true);
    Response.End();
```

This should allow you to display a image page within any block.